# What is the linux version of docker for mac k8s mode?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

On a Mac, Docker has a built in kubernetes mode that helps you set up a dev cluster in 1 click. Is there a way to do with with Docker-CE on my linux laptop? If not, what is the recommended approach (seems weird that this is actually easier on a mac or windows lol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the current OS version, try `kubectl get nodes -o wide`

If you're looking to run a local Kubernetes cluster, you should use Minikube: https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/

Comment: minikube is what I would be looking for... but is that really the simplest solution?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Based on your question, this is the simplest solution, but I'm curious if we can get more specific

Comment: just set up a dev cluster on my laptop so that I can test k8s yaml files locally. The equivalent of clicking the "kubernes" mode on Docker for Mac. Was hoping I had missed something :)

Comment: Ah ya in that case Minikube is definitely what you want

Comment: kubectl get node <nodename> -o jsonpath="{.status.nodeInfo.containerRuntimeVersion}"